# How to use dispose to prevent memory leak

Tags: flutter, dart

I've this init state method:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getNumber(index).then((number) {
      if (number> 1000) {
        number = number/ 1000;
        setState(() {
          flag = true;
          _num = number.toInt().toString();
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _num = number.toInt().toString();
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

And i got this error:

> This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a
>   widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent
>   widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can
>   occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation
>   callback. The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop
>   listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution
>   is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling
>   setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
>
> This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called
>   because another object is retaining a reference to this State object
>   after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks,
>   consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().

How i use dispose  in the right way?

Comment: you can use if(monunted) before setState to avoid calling setState when your widget is not in  widget tree  

if(monunted){
setState((){});
}

Comment: So actually i should use this before every setState in my app?

Comment: no only in async functions if you are navigating which changes widget tree

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can't account for this being a standard, but in my code I usually check for `mounted` in every `Future` event; whether it's `.then`, `.catchError`, or `.whenComplete` callbacks.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  getNumber(index).then((number) {
    if (!mounted) {
      return; // Just do nothing if the widget is disposed.
    }
    // ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I always override my setState method like following when using Futures, so you don't need to rewrite everywhere in the code...

```
void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) super.setState(fn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

> ###### This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.

**Solution**

1. Cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback.
2. Check the mounted property of the state class of your widget before calling `setState()`, like this:

   ```
   if (!mounted) return;

   setState(){
       /* ... */
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   if (mounted) {
     setState(() {
       /* ... */
     });
   }
   ```