# how to dispose setState properly to avoid memory leak?

Tags: flutter, cross-platform

It shows me this error.

```
E/flutter (22343): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter (22343): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter (22343): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
```

```
   @override
      void initState() {
         super.initState();
        if(mounted){
        getProfilePosts();
        getFollowers();
        getFollowing();
        checkIfFollowing();
        }
       
      }
    
      checkIfFollowing() async {
        if(mounted){
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
        });
        DocumentSnapshot doc = await followersRef
            .document(widget.profileId)
            .collection('userFollowers')
            .document(currentUserId)
            .get();
        setState(() {
          _isFollowing = doc.exists;
        });
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        }
      }
    
      getFollowers() async {
        if(mounted){
         setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
        });
        QuerySnapshot snapshot = await followersRef
            .document(widget.profileId)
            .collection('userFollowers')
            .getDocuments();
        setState(() {
          followerCount = snapshot.documents.length;
        });
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        }
      }
    
      getFollowing() async {
        if(mounted){
         setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
        });
        QuerySnapshot snapshot = await followingRef
            .document(widget.profileId)
            .collection('userFollowing')
            .getDocuments();
        setState(() {
          followingCount = snapshot.documents.length;
        });
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        }
      }
    
      getProfilePosts() async {
        if(mounted){
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
        });
        QuerySnapshot snapshot = await postsRef
            .document(widget.profileId)
            .collection('userPosts')
            .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
            .getDocuments();
        setState(() {
          postCount = snapshot.documents.length;
          posts = snapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you please reproduce the error on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev) and paste that code (or drop a gist link)?

Comment: It looks like `setState` might be getting executed after the Widget has already been marked dirty and removed from the tree, because you are `await`ing things before the `setState` call. Reproducing on DartPad will let us look at the issue more fully.

Comment: I think there's a lot of computations and awaitings in your `initState`. You trying to `setState` before the `build` method is called is possibly causing that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this in all the setState calls, it seems you check that only once, but the following calls to setState are unprotected

```
if (mounted == true) {
    setState(() {})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override setState to use it only if the State object is mounted on the widget tree.

```
@override
  void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) super.setState(fn);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (!mounted) return;

setState(){
    /* ... */
}
```

OR

```
if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
    /* ... */
  });
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74744364/13431819